# How to assign different IDs for duplicate data's in a list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

**What i need.**
I have a list of objects(list of icons). This data contain duplicate objects(since the same icons is used multiple times same property will repeat).so the ids of multiple object might be same. I need to loop this list with foreach and assign a unique id (named **uniquid** ) property to each object and add to a list.

**problem**
when I try to assign uniqueId to each object, duplicate objects will update with same unique id. How can i restrict this? i need all the objects should have a unique value in **uniqueid** property

```
List<icons> icons = new List<icons>();
foreach (var single in fullList)
{   
     Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
    single.uniquid = id;
    icons.Add(single);
}
```

here full list is also the  `List<icons>`

Comment: What is fullList ?

Comment: @kuldeep fulllist is  List<icons>

Comment: I do not get your problem, you said "duplicate objects will update with same unique id." -- but to me looks like each of the object of your fullList will get a unique Id, isnt this what you want ?

Comment: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c) - I'm going to guess that you have added the same instance of a refence type (i.e. a class) to the list twice.

Comment: @kuldeep fullList contain duplicate objects. but i need to differentiate this. so i added a new property called UniqueID. when i assign uniqueID inside foreach loop,uniqueID is mutating, and duplicate objects have same uniqueid.

Comment: can you add the class definition of `icon` ?